# Error to recording video strem with FFMPEG in Nodejs(using lib ffmpeg-static)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, stream, rtmp

When I start recording, terminal show me this error and stop recording :/

I need to recording in MP4 format. Is there any config to solve this problem?

```
  [sdp @ 0x7fbb02009e00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
    Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
    Input #0, sdp, from '/Users/user/Documents/4web-server/src/recording/h264.sdp':
      Metadata:
        title           : RTP Youtube
      Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
        Stream #0:1: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    [mp4 @ 0x7fbb0101a400] 
    dimensions not set
    Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
        Last message repeated 1 times
    Recording process exit, code: 1, signal: null
    Stop mediasoup RTP transport and consumer
    Recording stopped
```

My sdp config to make recording

```
v=0
    o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=RTP Youtube
    c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    t=0 0
    m=audio 5004 RTP/AVPF 111
    a=rtcp:5005
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    m=video 5006 RTP/AVPF 125
    a=rtcp:5007
    a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
    a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use node-media-server package for creating RTMP server. I am sharing you the configuration ....

```
const config = {
    server: {
        secret: 'kjVkuti2xAyF3JGCzSZTk0YWM5JhI9mgQW4rytXc'
    },
    rtmp_server: {
        rtmp: {
            port: 1935,
            chunk_size: 40000,
            gop_cache: true,
            ping: 60,
            ping_timeout: 30
        },
        http: {
            port: 8888,
            mediaroot: './media',
            allow_origin: '*'
        },
        trans: {
            ffmpeg: 'C:/src/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
            tasks: [
                {
                    app: 'live',
                    hls: true,
                    hlsFlags: '[hls_time=2:hls_list_size=3]',
                    mp4: true,
                    mp4Flags: '[movflags=frag_keyframe+empty_moov]',
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```